# How to enable j2ee statistics in yourkit

Tags: sql, jboss, yourkit

I am using trying to use yourkit for profiling an application deployed on JBoss.
Using this tutorial 
https://www.yourkit.com/docs/demo/JavaEE/JavaEE.htm
I created a .bat file to start the JBoss with Yourkit agent.
Unfortunately I cannot find in the Yourkit site what property should I use In order to be able to see what SQL queries are executed in the J2EE statistics section.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Java EE statistics is enabled by default https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/cpu_high_level.jsp and it will be recorded as soon as you start CPU profiling.

However, if Java EE related probes are off, then statistics will be missing. I recommend to use Java EE integration wizard from "Welcome" screen. It will create proper JVM options to enable profiling.